# VBA: Do While Loop does not want to looping

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table where I need to divide each number by the last one from the column and just iterate through each column once condition will be met. Then it should go out from the loop and move to the first loop. I give this loop argument that each time it should iterate by another line (the line below). Unfortunately, this does not work for me. It goes to the second loop, fill all cells in another sheet and it finishes after that. Program does not go to another row.

See my code, please let me know what I do wrong.

```
currentCol = 4
currentRow = 11


Do While originalSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value <> ""


     Do While currentHeader <> "Finish" 
        
        currentHeader = originalSheet.Cells(8, currentCol).Value
    
        divider1 = originalSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Value
        divider2 = originalSheet.Cells(17, currentCol).Value
    
        If divider1 <> 0 Then
            divisionResult = divider1 / divider2
        Else
            divisionResult = 0
        End If
    
        newSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Value = divisionResult
    
       
        currentCol = currentCol + 2
   
     Loop
        
 currentRow = currentRow + 1   
        
    
Loop
```

Comment: Move currentcol=4 to after the first do.  You never reset the value of currentcol, it just gets bigger and bigger so  that at the second iteration, currentcol is likely to be referring to an empty column outside of your data range.

Comment: It does not work at all. Same result as mine.

Comment: Please post a sample source data to let us to check.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
See my solution below.

```
currentRow = 11

Do While originalSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value <> ""

    currentCol = 4
    
    Do While originalSheet.Cells(8, currentCol).Value <> "Finish"
        
        divider1 = originalSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Value
        divider2 = originalSheet.Cells(17, currentCol).Value
    
        If divider2 <> 0 Then
            divisionResult = divider1 / divider2
        Else
            divisionResult = 0
        End If
    
        newSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Value = divisionResult
    
        currentCol = currentCol + 2
   
    Loop
    
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
        
Loop
```